# How to make multiple definitions in an elegant way?

Tags: syntax, associations

Consider the following code:

```
ilist = {0.1, 0.5, 3, 5}
{intTest[x, ilist[[1]]], intTest[x, ilist[[2]]], 
  intTest[x, ilist[[3]]], intTest[x, ilist[[4]]]} = 
 Interpolation[Table[{x, Exp[-x^#]/(x^# + 1)}, {x, 0., 1, 0.1}], 
     InterpolationOrder -> 1][x] & /@ ilist
```

It associates an interpolation `intTest` to the value of the particular element from `ilist`. In general, `ilist` may not be a list of numbers but just some string.

I would like to make this association rule independent of the number of elements of `ilist`, just to avoid something like the tedious construction

```
{intTest[x, ilist[[1]]], ..., intTest[x, ilist[[999]]]} =
```

I tried to make the following:

```
Clear[tabdefs]
tabdefs = intTest[x_, #] & /@ ilist
tabdefs = 
 Interpolation[Table[{x, Exp[-x^#]/(x^# + 1)}, {x, 0., 1, 0.1}], 
     InterpolationOrder -> 1][x] & /@ ilist
```

However, the last string does not work: instead of defining what is each element of `tabdefs` (namely, `intTest[x,ilist[[j]]]`) it defines `tabdefs` as a whole quantity.

Another attempt is

```
Do[intTest[x_, ilist[[i]]] = 
  Interpolation[
    Table[{x, Exp[-x^ilist[[i]]]/(x^ilist[[i]] + 1)}, {x, 0., 1, 
      0.1}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {i, 1, Length[ilist], 1}]
```

However, it looks a bit bulky, especially if the same routine association has to be made many times.

What is the correct syntax in this case?

Comment: First, the title (and the question) is a bit misleading because you refer to association but you are in fact doing down-values. Second, why don't you use simple `Do` with `i` iterating over `ilist` like `Do[intTest[x, i] = Interpolation[Table[{x, Exp[-x^i]/(x^i + 1)}, {x, 0., 1, 0.1}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {i, ilist}]`?

Comment: @Domen : Thanks, I will edit the question title. As for `Do`, earlier, I have edited the question by adding a similar solution. It is a bit bulky in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, yours is slightly bulky, mine not so much because I used only `i` iterated over `ilist` and then there is no need for `Length` or `ilist[[i]]`. I really don't see any true bulkiness anymore ... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "MapThread" is your friend. It will evaluate a function of n arguments over n lists. In your case, the function will be an assignment and  the first list is "ilist" and the second is a list of interpolating  functions, call it "funs".:

```
ilist = {0.1, 0.5, 3, 5}
funs = Interpolation[Table[{x, Exp[-x^#]/(x^# + 1)}, {x, 0., 1, 0.1}],
       InterpolationOrder -> 1][x] & /@ ilist;
```

Then MapThread will do all the assignments:

```
MapThread[(#1 = #2) &, {Table[intTest[x, ilist[[i]]], {i, 4}], funs}];
```

We can test if this worked e.g. by:

```
intTest[x, 0.5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For convenience lets define short-hand for the function generating the interpolations (my understand is that its form is besides the point anyway).

```
intfunc = Interpolation[Table[{x, Exp[-x^#]/(x^# + 1)}, {x, 0., 1, 0.1}], 
InterpolationOrder -> 1][x] &
```

We can then provide several compact ways of making the desired assignment that are agnostic to the length of `ilist`.

First:

```
Clear[intTest];
Evaluate[Table[intTest[x, i], {i, ilist}]] = intfunc /@ ilist
```

Second:

```
Clear[intTest];
Evaluate[intTest[x, #] & /@ ilist] = intfunc /@ ilist
```

Third:

```
(intTest[x, #] = intfunc[#]) & /@ ilist
```